# Register account through Facebook in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

The majority are looking for a login system with Facebook, but that's not my intention here. I've been reading all around for Facebook's login system via *oAuth 2.0*, but I'm looking for a registration system. I've also read about Facebook-like registration system, where you get a form that is styled like Facebook - Again, not looking for this one.

**What I'm interested in is this:**

- User goes to my website's native registration page
- The user is shown with the common registration fields and a **Register with Facebook** button
- If the user decides to use the Facebook button, he automatically skips over the normal method
- User clicks the Facebook register button
- I grab all the data somehow via oAuth (ID, Nickname, email) and register the user to my own DB *(?)*
- Once the user returns from Facebook to my website (callback URI), they can set a password for their account *(?)*
- User logs in as he's having a normal account on my website, through the normal login page

*The list items marked with (?) are the steps I'm having trouble to achieve and understand.*

So basically, I don't want to rely on Facebook each time an user comes to my website. I want to use Facebook only once and then the account is independent.

If this is a bad approach, please let me know why and tell me how the majority does it exactly. If someone could help me out with this I'd be very grateful.

My application is written in **PHP** and the DBMS is **MySQL**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the main thing that you **don't want** to happen is for your users to need to use 2 different systems to log into your application. They should be able to choose one and then continue using it without ever having to use the other method.

---

If your user chooses to use your **native login**, you take control and insert their information into the database. It'll probably be with a username + password so when they return, you would **match their login form to the data you have stored** and verify their identity like that.

---

If the user chooses **Facebook** as their login method, they will be redirected to the Facebook **app login**, get authenticated, get sent back to your site (callback URI) and then you'll be able to extract their information from Facebook's Graph API and save what you need to in your database for future use so that you wouldn't need to re-request that data again from Facebook. Stuff like the users first name, birthday, etc... Things that are not going to change.

You'll still have to use some unique identity field of the user for your database, I recommend that you use their Facebook user id.

When a *Facebook user* returns to your site - they will still click on the Facebook login button and still go through the same process as before - only this time, *Facebook* knows that they have already authenticated with this application, so the login process is handled behind the scene and the user arrives at your site already logged in. All you need to do from there is know what that user's id is (`/me`) and that's it!

One more scenario I should mention, is the case that the user is entirely logged out of Facebook when arriving at your site. In this case, you would still display a "login with Facebook" button and when the user enters the Facebook login flow, they will be requested to sign into Facebook first. Once that is done, still as part of the flow, the user will be redirected back to the app login, and then back to your site all in one go. It's something that Facebook handles and you don't need to worry about it at all.

> #### NOTE
>
> There is no need for an additional password on your side... This would cancel out the whole one-click-easy-login-hey-presto magic that makes the Facebook login plugin so effective.

Comment: You're right with the password thing, thanks for pointing that out. Now I understand how the process goes; I wasn't aware that I'd had to call Facebook's API. If I try to explain how I exactly thought this over, I would definitely fail - I had something weird in mind. Anyway, let's say that an user **registered** via Facebook (I provide this button in the registration page only, the user signed off his Facebook account, user comes to my website.... What happens? Must I provide a **Login with Facebook** button in my login page in this case? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Dugi - Yes, you would always show a login with Facebook button but if the user is not even logged into Facebook, they will be required to do so as part of Facebook's login flow... They would sign into Facebook first, then into your app all in one go. That's a great follow up question - I'll add a note on it in my answer..

Comment: So far so good, I almost got it. What I still need to know is that if it would be a good idea to remove the **Register with Facebook** button from the registration page and substitute it for a button in the login page that says **Sign in via Facebook** or something similar. I'd also appreciate if you showed me some real world example for what we've been talking about in PHP. I'm also planning to implement this idea with Twitter and Google, but I guess it's similar. I have apps registered at all mentioned services until now.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking look at the source code in the question I've asked:

[Facebook PHP SDK - User still shows as logged in on web app even though logged out of Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874980/facebook-php-sdk-user-still-shows-as-logged-in-on-web-app-even-though-logged-o)

You'll be specifically interested in the following part, which is after a user has logged in and authenticated your site to access their profile information:

`
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');

```
        function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }

        $id = test_input($user_profile['id']);
        $name = test_input($user_profile['name']);
        $first_name = test_input($user_profile['first_name']);
        $last_name = test_input($user_profile['last_name']);
        $link = test_input($user_profile['link']);
        $username = test_input($user_profile['username']);
        $gender = test_input($user_profile['gender']);
        $email = test_input($user_profile['email']);
        $timezone = test_input($user_profile['timezone']);
        $locale = test_input($user_profile['locale']);
        $verified = test_input($user_profile['verified']);

        $table_name= $wpdb->prefix . "fcm_fbusercreds";
        $currentmember_result = $wpdb->get_results(
            "
            SELECT *
            FROM $table_name
            WHERE id = $id
            "
        );

        if(empty($currentmember_result)){
            $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'lastupdated' => current_time('mysql'), 'id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name, 'link' => $link, 'username' => $username, 'gender' => $gender, 'email' => $email, 'timezone' => $timezone, 'locale' => $locale, 'verified' => $verified, 'coach' => "0" ) );
        } else {
            foreach ($currentmember_result as $result){
                $wpdb->update( $table_name, array( 'lastupdated' => current_time('mysql'), 'name' => $name, 'first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name, 'link' => $link, 'username' => $username, 'gender' => $gender, 'email' => $email, 'timezone' => $timezone, 'locale' => $locale, 'verified' => $verified, 'coach' => "0" ), array( 'id' => $result->id ) );
            }
        }
```

`

The code parses the Facebook user profile information and then either adds a user record into a database, or updates the user profile within the database.

If you have no intention of retaining permissions for future use, then I believe you can remove your "app" from having permissions to the user's profile.  You'll want to research that further.

Comment: I forgot to mention something on this... my code is specific to Wordpress.  Writing to the database if not using Wordpress will require that code to be modified.