# Facebook PHP SDK - User still shows as logged in on web app even though logged out of Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-php-sdk, logout

I'm working on a website for myself in order to provide coaching to people who are interested in joining fitness challenge groups.  To do this, I've decided to use Facebook as my platform for group correspondence.  Subsequently, I've begun working on incorporating Facebook login into my website (www.fitnesschallenges.net) and am mapping Facebook users who join a group to the corresponding group's database within my site.

The platform I'm using for my site is Wordpress and I've had to be somewhat creative in order to get the login / logout features working properly as a Wordpress plugin (by creating go between scripts - fblogin.php and fblogout.php).  Thus far, everything appears to work as it should with one exception... when a user logs out of Facebook, my site continues to show them as logged in.

I've done a number of searches for this particular problem, of which there are some others who've experienced the same behavior.  The result of my searches leads me to believe it has to do with sessions and/or establishing authentication tokens, but I'm very much a novice programmer and am looking for some direction on this.

Thanks in advance.

**userreg.php**
`

```
    global $wpdb;
    // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
    // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
    require_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php");

    $loginscript = plugins_url( 'fblogin.php', __FILE__ );
    $logoutscript = plugins_url( 'fblogout.php', __FILE__ );
    $challengeid = $atts['challengeid'];

    $config = array(
        'appId' => '#################',
        'secret' => '#################',
        'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
    );

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

    if($user_id) {
        // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
        // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
        try {

            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');

            function test_input($data) {
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
            }

            $id = test_input($user_profile['id']);
            $name = test_input($user_profile['name']);
            $first_name = test_input($user_profile['first_name']);
            $last_name = test_input($user_profile['last_name']);
            $link = test_input($user_profile['link']);
            $username = test_input($user_profile['username']);
            $gender = test_input($user_profile['gender']);
            $email = test_input($user_profile['email']);
            $timezone = test_input($user_profile['timezone']);
            $locale = test_input($user_profile['locale']);
            $verified = test_input($user_profile['verified']);

            $table_name= $wpdb->prefix . "fcm_fbusercreds";
            $currentmember_result = $wpdb->get_results(
                "
                SELECT *
                FROM $table_name
                WHERE id = $id
                "
            );

            if(empty($currentmember_result)){
                $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'lastupdated' => current_time('mysql'), 'id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name, 'link' => $link, 'username' => $username, 'gender' => $gender, 'email' => $email, 'timezone' => $timezone, 'locale' => $locale, 'verified' => $verified, 'coach' => "0" ) );
            } else {
                foreach ($currentmember_result as $result){
                    $wpdb->update( $table_name, array( 'lastupdated' => current_time('mysql'), 'name' => $name, 'first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name, 'link' => $link, 'username' => $username, 'gender' => $gender, 'email' => $email, 'timezone' => $timezone, 'locale' => $locale, 'verified' => $verified, 'coach' => "0" ), array( 'id' => $result->id ) );
                }
            }

            return '<a href="' . $logoutscript . '?final=0&ls=' . $logoutscript . '&site=' . site_url() . '&pp=' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '"><img src="' . plugins_url( 'images/fb_logout.png' , __FILE__ ) . '" width="240" height="30" alt="" /></a>';

        } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
            // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
            // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
            // just ask the user to login again here.

            error_log($e->getType());
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            return '<a href="' . $loginscript . '?redirect=1&site=' . site_url() . '&pp=' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '&ls=' . $loginscript . '"><img src="' . plugins_url( 'images/fb_login.png' , __FILE__ ) . '" width="240" height="30" alt="" /></a>';
        }   
    } else {
        // No user, print a link for the user to login
        return '<a href="' . $loginscript . '?redirect=1&site=' . site_url() . '&pp=' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '&ls=' . $loginscript . '"><img src="' . plugins_url( 'images/fb_login.png' , __FILE__ ) . '" width="240" height="30" alt="" /></a>';
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'fcmreg', 'fcm_fb' );
```

?>`

**fblogin.php**

`

```
$config = array(
    'appId' => '###################',
    'secret' => '###################',
    'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
);

$redirect = $_GET['redirect'];
$site = $_GET['site'];
$pagepath = $_GET['pp'];
$ls = $_GET['ls'];

if(isset($_GET['error'])){
    header("Location: " . $site . $pagepath);
    exit;
}

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

// If redirect is one, then this is for regular user registration
// if redirect is two, then this is for coach registration
if($redirect == 1){
    $params = array(
        'scope' => 'email',
        'redirect_uri' => $ls . '?redirect=' . $redirect . '&site=' . $site . '&pp=' . $pagepath . '&ls=' . $ls
    );
} elseif($redirect == 2) {
    $params = array(
        'scope' => 'email, user_online_presence, create_event, manage_friendlists, publish_actions, manage_pages',
        'redirect_uri' => $ls . '?redirect=' . $redirect . '&site=' . $site . '&pp=' . $pagepath . '&ls=' . $ls
    );
}

$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

if($user_id) {
    // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
    // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
    try {
        header("Location: " . $site . $pagepath);
    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        header("Location: " . $login_url);
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }   
} else {
    // No user, print a link for the user to login
    header("Location: " . $login_url);
}
```

?>`

**fblogout.php**

`

```
$config = array(
    'appId' => '################',
    'secret' => '################',
    'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
);

$ls = $_GET['ls'];
$site = $_GET['site'];
$pagepath = $_GET['pp'];
$final = $_GET['final'];

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$params = array('next' => $ls . '?final=1&ls=' . $ls . '&site=' . $site . '&pp=' . $pagepath);
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);

if($final == 0){
    header("Location: " . $logoutUrl);
}

if($final == 1){
    $facebook -> destroySession();
    header("Location: " . $site . $pagepath);
}
```

?>`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** A server side access token and user's actual facebook login status are independent of each other.  After getting a better understanding of your question, what you are trying to do is see the actual Facebook login status of a user.  You are not actually having an issue getting user's data from the API.  The best solution will be to use the Facebook Javascript API and the FB.getLoginStatus function: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

You can place this in your themes header.php file, or use a Wordpress filter to insert it after the opening `<body>` tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
            channelUrl: 'channel.html', // Channel File
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                jQuery('#facebook_status').html('User is logged into Facebook and Fitnesschallenges.net app');
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                jQuery('#facebook_status').html('User is logged into Facebook but not Fitnesschallenges.net app');
            } else {
                jQuery('#facebook_status').html('User is not logged into Facebook');
            }
        });

    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
</script>d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
</script>
```

Then place this in your page somewhere to be updated with the status:

```
<div id="facebook_status"></div>
```

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong... but I feel like I did exactly as you're talking to in option one (I want to use a server side solution only).  In the first file, userreg.php, I handle the FacebookApiException by returning an image with a link to login.  The result right now indicates there is no exception and subsequently returns a logout (even though the user is already logged out of Facebook).  Am I mis-understanding?

Comment: Sorry, I made the assumption fblogin.php was also being used for authenticating users who were not "registering" for the first time (wouldn't be forced to authenticate the FB app again) and that's where you had the issue.  So you are saying `$user_profile` is being populated correctly in userreg.php?

Comment: As I understand it, yes.  The userreg.php file is the file used for actually making the decision on the status of the user and then displaying the output.  In the case of a user being logged out of Facebook but somehow logged into my site, userreg.php is the only file used.  fblogin.php is used as a proxy more than anything.  This is done because I was unable to determine how to use the Wordpress shortcode without

Comment: Then there would not be an exception- or a reason for one.  If the user is logged in, authorized, and you can get their information, what is the problem in that file?  I still think your issue is in fblogin.php, as the try catch block there will never have an exception since you aren't even executing any Facebook SDK code in the try block.

Comment: ... with the SDK.  This is the same for fblogout.php as well.  In both cases, I'm passing URLs and redirect paths to them via redirect_uri and next variables within the params array.

Comment: So I just checked out your site- i think I understand your question now.  You aren't actually having an issue getting the users data- but you want their actual Facebook login status.  The server side access token the SDK uses doesn't care if a user is logged into Facebook or not, it will work until it expires.  You should use the JS SDK if you want to display whether or not a user is actually logged into Facebook.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, it is more about login status than anything... sorry for the confusion.  So.. is there a way to shorten the session such that it dies after a short period of time?  I thought it had to do with a session timeout thing and left it for roughly 8 hours before checking it again (was logged out of Facebook the entire time and accessing the site continued to show I was logged in).  I'm really looking for a Facebook-php-sdk solution rather than using the JS SDK.

Comment: After some further testing, it appears as though the session is limited to the user's browser remaining open.  If it is closed and reopened, the user is forced to log back in.  While this isn't a significant issue, I still wonder if there isn't a way to tie a user logging out of Facebook to a PHP website using the Facebook PHP SDK.